# How to find an object within a JS collection by value

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am working with an API right now and I am using `details[5].Value` to target information in the following format:

```
details:
    "value":[
        { 
            "ID": "6",
            "Name": "Links",
            "Value": "URL"
        },
        { 
            "ID": "7",
            "Name": "Other",
            "Value": "URL"
        }
        etc
    ]
```

The problem is that the location inside of the JSON response is likely to change in the future, making my code obsolete and as the url has the potential to change as well, I cannot target that.

I want a way to target the value of url, mostly, because of this, by the value of the `"Name"` property. However, if I use something like

```
_.where(details, { Name: "Links" }).Value
```

It comes back as undefined. I am not sure if there would be another way to get to the information?

Comment: `Array.prototype.find()`? and I think you need to find inside `details.value`

Comment: If I did details.value wouldn't it still need an index though considering that there is something called "Value" in more than one of the sub sections?

Comment: the structure of your `details` and what you want to find is pretty unclear, maybe you can add some explanation in question. I don't even think `details[5].Value` would work in your current example.

Comment: I don't understand the people that need a library to solve this kind of problem.  Using the js built-in function `find` it's enough.

Comment: @Ele when using Backbone, underscore is already available and the API is quite clean and works in all browsers without needing to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple points of confusion here.

[`_.where`](http://underscorejs.org/#where) returns an array:

> Looks through each value in the **list**, returning an array of all the values that contain all of the key-value pairs listed in **properties**.

so your `_.where(details, obj).Value` will (almost) always give you `undefined` because an array is unlikely to have a `Value` property. [`_.findWhere`](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) on the other hand does return a single value:

> Looks through the **list** and returns the first value that matches all of the key-value pairs listed in **properties**.

Secondly, your `details` appears to look like:

```
let details = {
    value: [
        { ID: '6', Name: 'Links', Value: 'URL' },
        { ID: '7', Name: 'Other', Value: 'URL' },
        ...
    ]
}
```

so you don't want to search `details`, you want to search `details.value`.

Putting them together:

```
_(details.value).findWhere({ Name: 'Links' }).Value
```

or

```
_.findWhere(details.value, { Name: 'Links' }).Value
```

You could use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (or [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) if you're looking for all matches) and write your own callback but you already have Underscore available so why bother? Furthermore, Backbone collections have `findWhere` and `where` methods and there are advantages to matching Backbone's overall terminology.

Comment: Beware that the example provided here assumes that there will always be an object returned. If no object is found, `.Value` at the end will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this mini function. Let me know if there is something wrong

### Update

This is the ES5 Version

```
function f(key, value, array){
    return array.value.filter(function(sub_array){
        return sub_array[key] == value;
    });
}
```

This is the ES6 Golfed Version

```
f=(k,v,a)=>a.value.filter(_=>_[k]==v)
```

```js
//This is your JSON 
var details = {
  value: [
    {
      "ID": "6",
      "Name": "Links",
      "Value": "URL"
    },
    {
      "ID": "7",
      "Name": "Other",
      "Value": "URL"
    }
  ]
}

// Short code
f=(k,v,a)=>a.value.filter(_=>_[k]==v)

// f is the function name
// Recives k = array key, v = value, a = array
// filter by the given key and value
// return the result as an array

console.log(f('Name', 'Links', details))
```

Comment: Why are you using underscore?  this code it's hard to read and more than that it's unnecessary writting code as you were a compiler.

Comment: I think codegolf is driving me crazy, sorry, i'll update the code

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using the Javascript built-in function **[`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** to get a specific object within an array.

- This alternative allows you to pass either an object or a string.
- If the `byThis` parameter is an object, the whole set of `key-values` must match with the `key-values` of every object within the target array.
- Otherwise, if `byThis` is a string every object will be treated as string to make the necessary comparison.

```js
let details = {  "value": [{    "ID": "6",    "Name": "Links",    "Value": "URL"  }, {    "ID": "7",    "Name": "Other",    "Value": "URL"  }]};

let findBy = (array, byThis) => {
  return array.find(o => {
    if (typeof byThis === 'object') return Object.keys(byThis).every(k => o[k] === byThis[k]);
    else if (typeof byThis === 'string') return o.toString() ===  byThis;
  });
}

let found = findBy(details.value, {Name: "Links"});

console.log(found);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is a Backbone app so they already have Underscore/Lodash on hand, your `findBy` function is duplicating the functionality that `_.findWhere`  already provides. In context, wouldn't it make more sense to just use _.findWhere` with the appropriate arguments?